# How to write mocha test for my module?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

need help with module test cover.
how to test if ws message ok==true || false?

I have next fnx:

```
wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
    ws.on('message', function (msg) {
        getItems(ws, db);
    });
});
```

getItems.js

```
module.exports.getitems = function (ws, db) {
try {
    var resData = new Object();
    resData.ok = true;

    db.collection('items').find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            ws.send({'ok': false});
        } else {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({'ok':true}));
        } 
    });
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e);

    ws.send(JSON.stringify({'ok': false}));
}
};
```

here what I've tried so far:

```
it('get items', function () {
mongo.connect(dbString)
    .then(function (currentDb) {

        wss.on('connection', function (ws) {
            console.log('connected');
            getItems(ws, currentDb);

           //how to test ws message ???
        });

    })
```

});

I am new in testing so not realy sure if even possible to test such module?
thanks in advance.

Comment: is this about - `msg` from the `message` event listener? at the moment you don't use it at all. If this is about the `ws.send()` - we do not know what it does. Your `getItems` function does not take a callback so I guess that the only way to somehow 'get' this object is the `send`method? Could you clarify what 'ws message' is and what `ws.send()` does? Another question that you can ask yourself is, if the usage of Promises would make your life easier here.

Comment: yes you are right. as I don't have callback I can use ws.send()

Comment: how to close question? I have done it.

Comment: feel free to answer your own question after revising it :)